# hiding part of text or string characters

Tags: tableau-desktop

I need to hide part of full name characters in tableau. Is it possible to achieve is as below;

[FullName] :Surname, FirstName MiddleName

SuXXXXe, FiXXXXXXe MiXXXXXXXe

Comment: Please DO NOT put the tag information back in the title. The tagging system works very well, and it does not need help by cluttering the title with that repeated information. I've removed it twice now - please do not make me do it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is achievable using the Left, Replace, Space and Right String Functions of Tableau.

`LEFT([string field],2) + REPLACE(SPACE(LEN(string field)-3), " ", "x") + RIGHT([string field],1)`

What the above function does is, if string field is "Revanth" then the left function gives me the first 2 letters of the string field, i.e, 'Re' and the Right function gives me the last letter of the string field 'h' and Space Function takes an argument in integer N where it generates " " N  times, and we replace " " by 'x' to satisfy your criteria.

Link for the string function documentation of tableau: https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/functions_functions_string.htm#replace

`LEFT(string,2) + REPLACE(SPACE(LEN(SPLIT(string,",",1))-3),"X")+ RIGHT(SPLIT(string,",",1),1) + "," + LEFT(SPLIT(SPLIT(string,",",2)," ",1),2) + REPLACE(SPACE(LEN(SPLIT(SPLIT(string,",",2)," ",1)-3)," ","X") + RIGHT(SPLIT(SPLIT(string,",",2)," ",1),1)+" "+LEFT(SPLIT(SPLIT(string,",",2)," ",2),2)+REPLACE(SPACE(LEN(SPLIT(SPLIT(string,",",2)," ",2)-3)," ","X") + RIGHT(SPLIT(SPLIT(string,",",2)," ",2),1)`

Comment: Thanks a lot Revanth. The first formula works very well but the second one has a syntax error.